# is there a way to subset an AnnData object after reading it in?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, subset

I read in the excel file like so:

```
data = sc.read_excel('/Users/user/Desktop/CSVB.xlsx',sheet= 'Sheet1', dtype= object)
```

There are 3 columns in this data set that I need to work with as .obs but it looks like everything is in the .X data matrix.

Anyone successfully subset after reading in the file or is there something I need to do beforehand?

Comment: what's `sc`?  Describe `data`.  `AnnData`?

Comment: `sc` here is the import for [scanpy](https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so assuming `sc` stands for [scanpy](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, the [`read_excel`](https://scanpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/scanpy.read_excel.html) just takes the first row as `.var` and the first column as `.obs` of the AnnData object.

The `data` returned by `read_excel` can be tweaked a bit to get what you want.

Let's say the index of the three columns you want in the `.obs` are stored in `idx` variable.

```
idx = [1,2,4]
```

Now, `.obs` is just a Pandas DataFrame, and `data.X` is just a Numpy matrix ([see here](https://anndata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). Thus, the job is simple.

```
# assign some names to the new columns
new_col_names = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']

# add the columns to data.obs
data.obs[new_col_names] = data.X[:,idx]
```

If you may wish to remove the `idx` columns from `data.X`, I suggest making a new AnnData object for this.